# How to extract array keys and values to get new array in php?

Tags: php, arrays

i have an associative array with keys category_id and item_code and their respective values as below

```
$arr = Array
(
 [0] => Array
    (
        [category_id] => 1
        [item_code] => RED 
    )
[1] => Array
    (
        [category_id] => 1
        [item_code] => GREEN
    )
[2] => Array
    (            
        [category_id] => 2
        [item_code] => BLUE
    )
[3] => Array
    (
        [category_id] => 3
        [item_code] => YELLOW
    )
[4] => Array
    (
        [category_id] => 3
        [item_code] => WHITE
    )
[5] => Array
    (
        [category_id] => 3
        [item_code] => BLACK
    )
);
```

now i want to extract this array to get new array like this

```
$new_arr = Array
 (
 [0] => Array
    (
        [0] => RED
        [1] => GREEN
    )
[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => BLUE
    )
[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => YELLOW
        [1] => WHITE
        [2] => BLACK
    )   
);
```

how can i get this new array? if you have any idea then please give me some suggestions. thanks

Comment: where is your code?your are post json string array?

Comment: Is the first array always sorted on category ID?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go:

```
foreach($arr as $v) {
  $new_arr[$v['category_id']][] = $v['item_code'];
}
$new_arr = array_values($new_arr);
```

Comment: This way there will be no $new_arr[0], right? Since there's no category_id of 0.